# AppImage not working on 22.04 even with Fuse installed

Tags: 22.04, appimage

this is my first post on askubuntu, so please bear with me.

I'm not able to run any AppImage file on my Ubuntu 22.04, even with Fuse installed. Maybe someone can help me by seeing the error it prints if I try to execute it in a terminal:

```
./Plexamp-4.2.2.AppImage Gtk-Message: 03:17:07.857: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module" Main: Window state x:undefined y:undefined w:270 h:515 fullscreen:undefined maximized:undefined Main: Display bounds x:undefined y:undefined w:undefined h:undefined Started Media Service: false Linux: Registering MPRIS service. libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name
= (null) libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null) libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name
= (null) [3824051:0713/031709.000984:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye. Trace/Breakpoint ausgelöst (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Adding this to the app image prints the same error

```
--appimage-extract-and-run
```

If anybody has an idea I'd be very grateful. I've done some research and all solutions suggest to have Fuse installed and nothing else, which I already did. From the error code it doesn't seem to be a Fuse issue anyway. So if anybody has an idea, let me know.

Comment: Looks like it's stuck in an infinite loop trying to open the HW GPU decoder. What's your GPU? What does glxinfo say about the driver?

Comment: glxinfo says a whole lot, but nothing too peculiar. Can you maybe point me where to look at? (Too much info to paste here).

I have a NVIDA RTX 3090 with NVIDIA drivers v515 installed

EDIT: Oh you already said what to look at. Well I found 

name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0 

And I found this 

OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.48.07

if that maybe answers your question

Comment: Other appimages do run, so you will need to contact the developper of that software.

Comment: Why do you think other appimages do run? They don't.  Tried it with 2 others and they don't run either, sadly

Comment: Thanks for the info. Usually these types of bugs is because the container cannot access the X11 server which can be due to a missing lib or access permissions. Try installing the NV driver from its website (warning: sometimes it renders your distro unable to boot into GUI). Or maybe you just need `apt install --reinstall libfuse2`

Comment: Thank you again @MatiasNGoldberg. I am going to try to install the latest package from Nvidia's website. However, what can I do if it really renders my distro unable to boot? Would I need to do a clean install then?

Comment: Clean install is the easiest way; but if you don't want to go that way you can uninstall the NVIDIA driver from command line (using the installer appending `--uninstall`) and hope it reverts what is messed up. How to restore it properly depends on what happened.
What helps a lot is to setup an SSH server first so you can still access your computer from a laptop (and even mount the entire filesystem via SSH to edit files or view logs from a comfy GUI, like e.g. /var/log/Xorg.0.log)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I just clean installed Ubuntu and the same issue happened on  the previous install too. Is it possible that my GPU has just a hardware fault? Besides that everything else is working quite well though. Just the problem with the AppImages.

But to make a long story short I already ditched the AppImage version of the app I wanted to install and got the flatpak pendant, which works very well. But really appreciated your help

Comment: @Donatus I don't know if the Plex desktop app is built using Chromium, but if it is, you may try using the Chromium flag: --no-sandbox

For example: ./Plex.AppImage --no-sandbox